# Ubuntu Hacked - Attempted to Kill Init

Tags: malware

I recently got hacked via Omegle. I realised that the person was able to control my cursor and my keyboard as well. So, I shut off my machine as soon as I realised it.

I turned it on later, to realise that my packages were getting deleted on their own. It started with sudo, and then the terminal and then when I restarted I got the following message :
 `Attempted to kill init`.

I can't even open it on the recovery mode. Any ideas how to fix this?

Edit : I removed the partition entirely. Do I run the risk of catching the virus again?

Comment: You might be able to use a liveUSB session to recover your files. For myself, I would be worried that if I recovered my installation that the system would still be compromised in some way.

Comment: If I remove the partition that had Ubuntu, do I run the risk of catching the virus again? @stratus

Comment: @Quark only if you are recovering files that are compromised.  If your system is that compromised, however, you should probably accept the fact your data is compromised, and that there's a high likelihood you might get re-compromised during data recovery and should probably just start anew without your old data.  Removing the partition doesn't remove the *data* on disk, so you still need to overwrite the disk/drive/etc. with zeroes or random data.  At least, depending on the infection vector.

Comment: @Thomas Ward I deleted my Ubuntu Partition and am reinstalling a different version of Ubuntu in the same partition.